# Setup Identity for an Application Pool as LocalSystem in Azure

Tags: iis, azure, localsystem

Is there a way to do this in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` or other place without go to the IIS and adjust by hand?

I tried `executionContext="elevated"` for webrole, not working.

**UPDATE**

If you install "IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility" on Azure IIS, the error I shown below will gone.

**This raise another issue, howto install "IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility" automatically at deployment stage on Azure.**

---

*@astaykov, I like to comment but the code below too big, so I use this place.*

I use the same code that wrote by Wade Wagner as:

```
public override bool OnStart()
        {
            // http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureChangeAppPoolIdentit-27099828
            // This variable is used to iterate through list of Application pools 
            string metabasePath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools";
            string appPoolName;
            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                //Get the name of the appPool that is created by Azure 
                appPoolName = serverManager.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web"].Applications.First().ApplicationPoolName;
                // Get list of appPools at specified metabasePath location 
                using (DirectoryEntry appPools = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath))
                {
                    // From the list of appPools, Search and get the appPool that is created by Azure  
                    using (DirectoryEntry azureAppPool = appPools.Children.Find(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool"))
                    {
                        if (azureAppPool != null)
                        {
                            // Refer to: 
                            // http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e3a60d16-1f4d-44a4-9866-5aded450956f.mspx?mfr=true,  
                            // http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/  
                            // for more info on AppPoolIdentityType 
                            azureAppPool.InvokeSet("AppPoolIdentityType", new Object[] { 0 });  // MD_APPPOOL_IDENTITY_TYPE_LOCALSYSTEM
                            // Write above settings to IIS metabase 
                            azureAppPool.Invoke("SetInfo", null);
                            // Commit the above configuration changes that are written to metabase 
                            azureAppPool.CommitChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            RoleInRun = true;
            TaskInRun = false;
            return base.OnStart();
        }
```

I can get rigth value at `appPoolName`, But error happened here:
`using (DirectoryEntry azureAppPool = appPools.Children.Find(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool"))`

I am searching solutions everywhere but still cannot find a clue
Error below, from IIS events:

```
Application: WaIISHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(System.String, System.String)
   at GimmeRank.Redirector.WebRole.OnStart()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleType)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Anyideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

executionContext="elevated" will only run your RoleEntryPoint as the local SYSTEM account, but it is not the IIS pool identity.

You may want to check out [this blog post by Wade Wagner](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/). What he describes there, can be run in your OnStart method along with executionContext="elevated" (because only admin can change pool identity). If that does not work for Local System, you can create a user for RDP, it will added in the Administrators group, and you can set the iis app pool identity to that user.

**UPDATE**

Hm, I used the following method (which is similar) and it worked fine:

```
private void SetAppPoolIdentity()
{
    string appPoolUser = "myRDP_admin_user";
    string appPoolPass = "my_super_secure_password";

    Action<string> iis7fix = (appPoolName) =>
    {
        bool committed = false;
        while (!committed)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager())
                {
                    var applicationPool = sm.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];
                    applicationPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
                    applicationPool.ProcessModel.UserName = appPoolUser;
                    applicationPool.ProcessModel.Password = appPoolPass;
                    sm.CommitChanges();
                    committed = true;
                }
            }
            catch (FileLoadException fle)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Trying again because: " + fle.Message);
            }
        }
    };

    // ServerManager in %WinDir%System32InetSrvMicrosoft.Web.Administration.dll
    var sitename = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web";
    var appPoolNames = new ServerManager().Sites[sitename].Applications.Select(app => app.ApplicationPoolName).ToList();
    appPoolNames.ForEach(iis7fix);
}
```

Could you try that? Note that it will not work with Local System account, as it is not real account and we cannot set it this way (at least I don't know how to do it, but with specific account for RDP it works fine).

Answer (score 0):

Create start.cmd:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('%windir%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD list wp /text:apppool.name') DO (

%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD set config /section:applicationPools /[name='%%A%':'].processModel.identityType:LocalSystem

)
```